# Gradle Build Running since 57 Minutes?

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

I am sorry if this question is repeat but gradle is taking much longer time then before. It is running since 57 min as you can see in screenshot and in previous attemp it took only one or half minute and usually it builds app in 2-3 minutes maximum. But from 2,3 days it behaving strangely. Running forever without any reason. Any help?

[image: Gradle taking long time than ever]

Comment: can we know system specfications you were using

Comment: Core 2 Duo CPU with 4 GB Ram Windows 7. Gradle normally takes 2-3 min when building but sometime it takes forever.

Answer (score 0):

In Android Studio go to File -> Settings -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Build Tools -> Gradle

Check 'Offline work' under 'Global Gradle settings'

It will reduce 90% gradle build time.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

While offline builds and reinstall may be a solution, we still need to get down to the exact reason.

Is it possible for you to run the gradle command with a stacktrace or a debug info? Even if the build hangs sporadically, you lose nothing by putting out a debug log. At best, there will some information which can be analyzed further.

Comment: I am kind of beginner. Can you tell me how to do this?

Comment: Two questions before we reach the answer

Comment: Two questions before we reach the answer
1. Can we build Android projects from gradle command line? Yes. Here is the link: https://developer.android.com/studio/build/building-cmdline.html

2. What are the command line opts for gradle: Again, the standard reference is this; https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/tutorial_gradle_command_line.html

Having mentioned both, the first step would be to run gradle --help on the command prompt, opened on your Android project directory. A list of options shows up. Of your specific interest would be the -s and the -i command line parameters

Comment: -S, --full-stacktrace   Print out the full (very verbose) stacktrace for all exceptions.
-s, --stacktrace        Print out the stacktrace for all exceptions.

Couple these with the -i parameter: 
-i, --info              Set log level to info.

and you will have loads of information telling you where the build takes its time.. Have fun!!